# Gain of a differential amplifier in PSpice

Tags: mosfet, analog, modeling, pspice

I am modelling a differential amplifier in PSPice using MOSFET. Here is the schematic:

[image]

In this i want to track the gain of the circuit by changing the value of the width of NMOS. Now can anybody please help me out here how can i perform this in PSPice i.e by the help of which tools and how?

P.S: I know that i could have found this over the internet but i m=need to work on this urgently so please help me out here.
**I know how to code, i just want to know what tools to use like to plot the graph or anything which shows the gain for various values of W**

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to create a MOSFET in PSpice is

```
 M<name> <drain node> <gate node> <source node>
+ <bulk/substrate node> <model name>
+ [L=<value>] [W=<value>]
+ [AD=<value>] [AS=<value>]
+ [PD=<value>] [PS=<value>]
+ [NRD=<value>] [NRS=<value>]
+ [NRG=<value>] [NRB=<value>]
+ [M=<value>] [N=<value>]
```

The `L` and `W` values refer to the length and width of the device.

Comment: please see the edits in the question.

Comment: So you want us to find the PSpice command to make a graph for you too? Have you considered reading the manual?